# Кодировка БД в командной строке windows

Tags: php, база-данных, кодировка, phpmyadmin

При запросе данных с БД в командной строке windows кириллица выводится в виде кракозябр. При чем такая проблема исключительно при выводе данных в командной строке, в phpMyAdmin и браузере все отображается корректно. В чем может проблема?

Comment: в кодировке командной строке, очевидно... пробуй команду `chcp 65001` например чтоб поменять на ютф... или какая требуется

Comment: Помогло, но теперь вместо кракозябр везде вопросительные знаки...а как поменять на cp1251?

Comment: `chcp 1251` соответственно ..... также надо бы попробовать в дополнение использовать шрифт `Lucida console `

Comment: Благодарствую, помогло окончательно :)